# "Properties" context option on a file in Visual Studio does not do anything

Tags: visual-studio-mac

In `Visual Studio` I am right-clicking on `appsettings.json` to bring up the context menu and selected the `Properties` option.

[image]

Nothing happened.  I am on `macOS`.  For a coworker who also has `Visual Studio` [and also on macOS] that same option brings up a dialog with various settings to customize.  What might be happening here?

Comment: It should open the Properties window. You can also open the Properties window from the  View main menu. If you use the main menu does it open the Properties window? If not then I would try re-setting the window layout, which you can do from the main menu under the Window menu item.

Comment: @MattWard  I just tried again and the `Properties` panel does show up. I made an answer - it can be helpful for readers to know it should really be there like you say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Properties` panel is showing up now on the right hand side. I'm not aware of any particular change I made in the environment or project.

[image]